# RecyclerView items with Section Header (Dynamic update of elements at any position)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design

I want to show a RecyclerView with section header. I am referring this example https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058, this works fine. But I want to insert or delete element (with or without section header) at any position. I have tried some ways by extending above code. But didn't find any optimal solution. Is there any one solved this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter):

#### 1) Add gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.+'
}
```

#### 2) Create a custom Section class:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(10);

    public MySection() {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_item);
    }

    public void addItem(int position, String item) {
        myList.add(position, item);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        myList.remove(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return myList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(myList.get(position));
    }
}
```

#### 3) Create a custom ViewHolder for the items:

```
class MyItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView tvItem;

    public MyItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
    }
}
```

#### 4) Set up your ReclyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

MySection mySection = new MySection();

// Add your Sections
sectionAdapter.addSection(mySection);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

#### 5) Add/remove your items to/from the Section:

```
mySection.addItem(1, "Item 1");
mySection.remove(0);

sectionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks dude. Nice library.

Comment: hi Gustavo, can you please check out my question regarding your library http://stackoverflow.com/q/39817679/1701077 ?